# HTTP GET request format + iOS 9 + Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, get, swift2, httprequest, ios9.3

I am having trouble completing a GET request to my server. I am getting a response from the server, all of the parameters are being accepted except for the last one which is the signature. Below is the documentation authorization.

```
https://api.mySite.com/oauth/authorize?
```

Parameters are to be appended onto the API URL as shown:

```
'app_id=APP_ID&response_type=token&email=EMAIL&password=PASSWORD:APP_SECRET'
```

Here is the code that makes up the request along with the response I am getting from the server.

```
let request_format = api_url + "app_id=\(app_id)&" + "response_type=\(response_type)&" +
        "email=\(email)&" + "password=\(md5_pass.lowercaseString)" + ":\(app_secret)"
```

Response:

```
{"field":"sig","error_msg":"sig is incorrect","code":"#2"}
```

I am even using online MD5 calculator for sanity checks to make sure that the correct hash is being calculated. Can anyone spot anything going on here? app_id , app_secret , email , and password parameters all check out. I was still getting the same response before I added the .lowercaseString to the password hash.

Comment: You check your server side what request you are sending to server.

Comment: https://api.domainName.com/oauth/authorize?app_id=MY_APP_ID&response_type=token&email=MYEMAIL&password=MD5_HASHED_PASSWORD&sig=MY_APP_SECRET